# UICollectionView with multi-select won't select more than a dozen of items

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

When using a `UICollectionView` with `allowsMultipleSelection` set to YES only a dozen items are selectable. `UICollectionViewDelegate` stops calling `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`.

It seems very random. You can select a few items, scroll down, select some more, and at some point you're not able to select any more items.

When the cell is smaller you seem to be able to select more items. The larger the cell, the fewer items you're able to select before it stops working.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have discovered that while my previous answer works, it may be caused by not calling super. While the documentation for `UICollectionReusableView` fails to mention this, the documentation for `UITableViewCell`, which has the same method, does.

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse]
    // Your code here.
}
```

**Old Answer:**

---

This may be a bug with the `UICollectionView`.

What's happening is cells that were previously selected are being reused and maintain the selected state. The collection view isn't setting `selected` to "NO".

The solution is to reset the the selected state in `prepareForReuse` of the cell:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    self.selected = NO;
}
```

If the reused cell is selected, the collection view will set `selected` to "YES" after `prepareForReuse` is called.

This is something the `UICollectionView` should be doing on it's own. Thankfully the solution is simple. Unfortunately I spent a ton of time working around this bug by tracking my own select state. I didn't realize *why* it was happening until I was working on another project with smaller cells.

Comment: Thank you, Luke! I agree, this feels like a bug, so I've reported it: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2816402

Comment: @clozach: I just updated this; I think it may be caused by not calling super. The documentation doesn't mention this, but the docs for `UITableViewCell`'s `prepareForReuse` does mention this. It may be just a documentation problem.