# Selecting multiple values shuffle when scrolled: UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, uicollectionview

Trying to select the multiple cells in UICollectionView and when scrolled the selection c hanges. Why it is happening, please guide.
Below is code. i tried.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
printf("Selected View index=%d",indexPath.row);

itemPaths  = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];

UICollectionViewCell* cell=[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_s.png"]];
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UICollectionViewCell* cell=[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow_seat.png"]];

}
```

What else should i try.

Comment: I found a workaround for this on StackOverflow: set the cell's selected state to NO in prepareForReuse. for this see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556476/uicollectionview-with-multi-select-wont-select-more-than-a-dozen-of-items

Comment: @SAMIR RATHOD where to declare and call this method "prepare for reuse"

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing to solve this problem you can give tag to each cell using custom cell of UICollection View so that it will have unique identity

Answer (score 0):

Since you are likely reusing your cells, when you hand the cells back out (cellForItemAtIndexPath) you need to check if the indexPath is selected and color up your cell.  You will likely want to decolor your cells too since the reuse function may send back a colored up cell in some cases when it should not.