# How do I select multiple cells in a collection view and delete the selected cells?

Tags: swift, ios8, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have created the collection view which displays the images which i selected from photo library.I have a DetailViewController to display the selected image in larger view and I can delete a selected image from the DetailViewController. Now i want to select more than one image in Collection View itself and delete those from the view.
And i have used,
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

But its not allowing me to select multiple items. 
Can anybody please help me to do this

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556476/uicollectionview-with-multi-select-wont-select-more-than-a-dozen-of-items